# How to select rows with one of two column values can't be null?

Tags: hive, hiveql

For example:

```
hive> select mid, tag1, tag2, dt from message_use_tags where dt="20211107" and (tag1 != '' or tag2 != 'NULL') limit 50;
```

I want to specify:

1. date = '20211107'
2. tag1 and tag2 can't be both empty string at the same time. One of them can be empty. However, the following doesn't achieve the purpose:

   tag1 != '' or tag2 != 'NULL'

In the result set, there are rows where both tag1 and tags are empty strings. How to modify the statement to get the results desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hive> select mid, tag1, tag2, dt from message_use_tags where dt="20211107" and (tag1 != '' or tag2 != 'NULL') and (tag1 != '' and tag2 != '') limit 50;
```

Comment: tag2 != 'NULL'?

Comment: (tag1 != '' and tag2 != ''): Both can't be empty?

Comment: can u try this hive> select mid, tag1, tag2, dt from message_use_tags where dt="20211107" and not (tag1 = '' and tag2 = '') limit 50;

Comment: Yes. It seems working correctly!

Comment: Can you also please see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390192/how-to-use-casted-column-as-where-clause-condition-in-hive